# MySQL update with REGEXP condition

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I need to update some phone numbers starting like :

`39 9xxxxx` `39 8xxxxx` `from 9 to 4` adding `0 in front`

But I need to find only phone numbers with `39[4-9]xxxxx`

```
UPDATE table SET phone_number = CONCAT(
REPLACE(
    LEFT(phone_number,2), '39', '390'),      
    SUBSTRING(phone_number, 2, CHAR_LENGTH(phone_number)
)) WHERE phone_number REGEXP '^[4-9]{3}';

stuck in here   ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Any help or idea?

Comment: Normally you would use a simple where condition in the select like this: `WHERE phone_number LIKE '39 9%'`. The '%' is the wildcard here. However, I don't quite understand exactly what you want to change, your explanation is not very clear.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I want to replace all combinations from `394 to 399` with `3904, 3905, 3906` etc... that could be made in 6 different queries but in one query... only regexp will handle I think, or with `OR` condition....

Comment: Ok, I get it. So there's no space behind the initial '39' as you showed in your question? You could do `WHERE LEFT(phone_number,3) IN (394,395,396,397,398,399)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will do what you want. It uses a REGEXP to match numbers that start with 394 to 399:

```
UPDATE numbers 
SET phone_number = CONCAT(LEFT(phone_number, 2), '0', SUBSTR(phone_number, 3))
WHERE phone_number REGEXP '^39[4-9]'
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/611610/1)